# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException when inserting into MySQL database using PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm making an application on javafx connected to a MySQL database in which I want the user's input to be saved, so I'm using a PreparedStatement. I keep getting this exception, as shown below, and I don't know how to fix it and what I'm doing wrong.
I'm using FXML, so below is the controller class for the scene.
Please help me out!

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class AddVolunteerSceneController implements Initializable {

    ObservableList<String> skillList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Communication", "Writing", 
            "Graphic Designing", "Social Media Marketing","Analytical Thinking",
            "Leadership","Teamwork","Teaching","Resource Management");
    ObservableList<Department> deptList = FXCollections.observableArrayList (
            new Department(1, "Data Analysis"),
            new Department(2,"Art & Media"),
            new Department(3, "Fundraising"),
            new Department(4,"School Resources"),
            new Department(5,"Social Media"),
            new Department(6,"Technology"),
            new Department(7,"Newsletter & Journalism"));

    
    
    @FXML public TextField txtForename;
    @FXML public TextField txtSurname;
    @FXML public TextField txtSchool;
    @FXML public TextField txtEmail;
    @FXML public TextField txtPhone;
    @FXML public ComboBox<Department> comboboxDept;
    @FXML public DatePicker datepickJoin;
    @FXML public ChoiceBox<String> choiceboxSkill;
    @FXML public Button btnSave;
    @FXML public TextField txtVolID;
    @FXML public Button btnCancel;
    @Override
    
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        try {
            Connection conn = driver.connector();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        choiceboxSkill.setItems(skillList);
        comboboxDept.setItems(deptList);
    }


    
public void saveButton (ActionEvent event) throws SQLException {
    
    Department department = comboboxDept.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    System.out.println(department.getID());
    String query = "INSERT INTO volunteers (forename,surname,school,phone,email,joinDate,skill,deptID) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement pst = driver.connector().prepareStatement(query); 

    try {       

        pst.setString(1, txtForename.getText());
        pst.setString(2, txtSurname.getText());
        pst.setString(3, txtSchool.getText());
        pst.setString(4, txtPhone.getText());
        pst.setString(5, txtEmail.getText());
        pst.setDate(6, java.sql.Date.valueOf(datepickJoin.getValue()));
        pst.setString(7, choiceboxSkill.getValue());
        pst.setInt(8, department.getID());
        //Statement stmt = driver.connector().createStatement();
         
        pst.executeUpdate(query);
        AlertBox.display("Alert", "Data Saved Successfully");
    }
    
    catch(SQLException E) {
        E.printStackTrace();
        AlertBox.display("Alert", "Error in saving data.");
    }
}


}
```

Department Class

```
public class Department {
    public int id;
    public  String deptName;
    public Department (int id, String deptName) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.deptName = deptName;
    }
    public int getID() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setID(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public  String getDeptName() {
        return deptName;
    }
    public void setDeptName(String deptName) {
        this.deptName = deptName;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getDeptName();
    }
    }
```

The exception:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1335)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2108)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1245)
    at NDvolunteersDB.addVolunteerSceneController.saveButton(addVolunteerSceneController.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:410)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
```

Comment: java naming conventions, please! This doesn't look like related to fx, solve the db error separately (its message tells you what's wrong)..

Comment: Use `pst.executeUpdate();`. You don't want to use the original `query` string again, at this point. It's not a valid SQL statement (hence the error) and it has already served its purpose as a template for the actual SQL to be executed.

Comment: @andrewjames thank you so much!! that worked.

Comment: @khushi - please read the answers in the linked question, as well (Where it says "_This question already has answers..._"). There are some important points there about how to close your JDBC resources correctly, using `finally`.